# Excel-Vlookup : lookup value repeated + add column value for similar lookup values

Tags: excel, vlookup

I'm struggling with a formula, in fact I don't know where to start. I'm ok with Vlookup when it's easy stuff, but this one is tough for me and don't even know to put it in words. But I'll try.

So, basically, I have a raw data that I extract from Analytics for my campaigns (performance per hours), so my campaigns names are repeted. I want to crate a formula that will allow me to extract all revenues from my campaigns and return the total revenu for each one.

I've created a small example to illustrate my need:

[image]

Thank you in advance,

Comment: You can use Subtotal option which is located in the Data tab, grouped in Outline

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into that.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you want a Pivot Table. Select your data from A2:B12 then Insert -> Pivot Table. Pull Campaign to rows and Revenue to values and it will sum the revenue for each Campaign, which is what you have in Results.

Comment: Tanhk you. I didn't think about that, but I got it sorted with SUMIFS.